# How to create duplicate rows as per column "Class" in Excel

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have columns for "Name" and "Class."

I want to generate duplicate Rows for each class with identical names one by one as per the Class column, which has numerous classes separated by a comma. How it should be done in Excel

**Current data:**

| Name | class |
| --- | --- |
| Suresh | A, B, C, D |
| Naresh | B, C, D, E |

**Expected Output:**

| Name | class |
| --- | --- |
| Suresh | A |
| Suresh | B |
| Suresh | C |
| Suresh | D |
| Naresh | B |
| Naresh | C |
| Naresh | D |
| Naresh | E |

Comment: Using Power Query, you can split the class column on the comma and then unpivot.  Plenty of examples using power query to unpivot on this group.  Give it a try and post back with your results (and code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data is in A1:B3.

in E2 put :

```
=A2
```

in E3 put :

```
=IF(J2=1,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+1),E2)
```

in F2 put :

```
=LEFT(H2,I2-1)
```

in H2 put :

```
=IF(COUNTIF($E$1:E2,E2)=1,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,))&",",TRIM(RIGHT(H1,LEN(H1)-I1)))
```

in I2 put :

```
=FIND(",",H2)
```

in J2 put :

```
=LEN(H2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(H2,",",""))
```

except for E2, drag all downwards.

Idea : H2 loads the list base on Name(E2) value & add 1 more "," > I2 finds the the 1st "," > J2 do the "," count & F2 loads the element. Base on previous row column J value, Name(E3) will change/stay the same.

Please share if it work/understandable/not.